# how to get a probability distribution for a topic in mallet?

Tags: java, machine-learning, topic-modeling, mallet, topicmodels

Using mallet I can get a specific number of topics and their words. How can I make sure topic words make a probability distribution (ie sum to one)?

For example if I run it as bellow, how can I use the outputs given by mallet to make sure probabilities of topic words for topic 0 adds up to 1?

```
mallet train-topics --input text.vectors --output-topic-keys topics.txt --output-doc-topics doc_comp.txt --topic-word-weights-file weights.txt --num-top-words 50 --word-topic-counts-file counts.txt --num-topics 3 --output-state topicstate.gz --alpha 1
```

Comment: I'm assuming your weights.txt file contains the weighting given to each word in a topic? It's been a while since I used Mallet but you should be able to just open this file in something like Excel and sum the topic word weights?

Comment: yes but it doesn't sum to one. is it ok if I just L1 or L2 normalize the weights or is there any particular way of doing this?

Comment: Could you post the weight of the top 10 terms in a topic? I think you may need to normalise. If I remember correctly when I used Mallet some words would have a weight greater than 1.

Comment: I _think_ the probabilities would wind up being p(word|topic) = `(count[topic, word] + alpha / num_word_types) / (sum(count[topic, w] for w in words) + alpha)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get word-topic probability using mallet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661094/how-to-get-word-topic-probability-using-mallet)