# How to get probability of topic given a query using Mallet

Tags: machine-learning, information-retrieval, topic-modeling, mallet, topicmodels

I want to use [Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu) as a part of an expert finding project. I'm almost new to Mallet but I know that it trains topics from a set of the documents. Let's say that I have 50 topics trained by Mallet. I want to calculate this probability: `p(topic|q)` or either `p(q|topic)`

`q` is the query. It's a word (such as algorithm, android and etc) which I'm desired to find the experts in the specified area.

As I read this post : [how to get word-topic probability using mallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661094/how-to-get-word-topic-probability-using-mallet/37408559#37408559), One of the users said we can calculate the probability using `--word-topic-counts-file` option. Let's say that I have generated this file by Mallet. It has the following structure:

```
0 android 2:21
1 is 3:3
.
.
.
```

I know the semantic of this structure, But I don't know how can I calculate the probability of topic given query ( i.e. `p(topic|q)` or either `p(q|topic)` )

P.S: I use the word "either" because I'm not sure mallet calculates which of them

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this example line from [GlieBrt's answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661094/how-to-get-word-topic-probability-using-mallet/37408559#37408559)

```
1 needham 19:2 17:1
```

Here p(topic|q) can be calculated as

p(19|needham) = 2/3 = 0.67

and

p(17|needham) = 1/3 = 0.33

With you own example, it is even simpler:

```
0 android 2:21
```

p(2|android) = 1.0

Comment: Thank you, I really got stuck on this problem